# Apache POI ClassCastException when reading xlsx File Rows

Tags: java, jsp, apache-poi, classnotfoundexception

I am writing a class that uses the apache-poi library to iterate through an xlsx worksheet and grab some UPC numbers. The application itself runs on a TOMCAT server - the code compiles without any errors but I'm getting a strange run time error anyone have any idea why this happens? I used maven to grab the poi dependencies so this is a bit unexpected:

```
type Exception report

message org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow cannot be cast 
to org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it 
from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
    com.riverboat.util.RiverBoatExcelParser.parseXLSManifest(RiverBoatExcelParser.java:51)
    com.riverboat.servlets.FileManagerServlet.doPost(FileManagerServlet.java:113)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.53 (1.6.0.2) logs.

Edit: Here is the Pom File

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-     instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>RiverBoat</groupId>
<artifactId>RiverBoat</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the java code:

```
package com.riverboat.util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class RiverBoatExcelParser {

FileInputStream spreadsheet;

public RiverBoatExcelParser(InputStream file)
{
    spreadsheet = (FileInputStream)file;
}

/*
 * Parse an XLS spread sheet
 */
public void parseXLSManifest(int book, String UPCColumnHeader)
{
    String currText;
    boolean foundUPC = false;
    List<ExcelManifestRecord> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int current_row = 0;
    int current_col = 0;
    int upc_row;
    int upc_col=0;

    try {
        //Create workbook instance to hold file reference to .xlsxfile
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(spreadsheet);

        //Get first/desire sheed from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(book);

        //Iterate through each row one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while(rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            //For each row,  iterate through all the colums
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            ExcelManifestRecord rec = new ExcelManifestRecord();

            while(cellIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                current_col++;

                switch(cell.getCellType())
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        currText = cell.getStringCellValue();

                        //check for the upc column header
                        if(currText.equalsIgnoreCase(UPCColumnHeader))
                        {
                            upc_col = current_col;
                            foundUPC = !foundUPC;       
                        }
                        //TODO: init row/column 
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        if(current_col == upc_col && foundUPC)
                        {
                            rec.UPC = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            System.out.println("Found UPC "+rec.UPC);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            current_col = 0;
        }           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your pom file, I suspect a version conflict.

Comment: I added the pom file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need this dependency for xssf:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't get compile errors now it means you have this dependency from somewhere else, likely your RiverBoat project exposes an older/incompatible version. So either you need both poi dependencies in this pom, or none (as both may be exposed by RiverBoat).

Comment: Ah, okay thanks. I had an older version in my TOMCAT library files that was causing the problem. I added this dependency to the pom and it works now.